# the compiler doesn't seem to accept Agent class

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

probably the answer is quite silly but I need a pair fresh of eyes to spot the problem, if you will. this is the excerpt from _tmain:

```
Agent theAgent(void);
int m = theAgent.loadSAG();
```

and this is agent.h, which I included in _tmain:

```
#ifndef AGENT_H
#define AGENT_H
class Agent {
public:
Agent(void);
int loadSAG(void);
~Agent(void);
};
#endif
```

and agent.cpp relevant function:

```
int Agent::loadSAG(void) {
return 3;
}
```

so why in the world I get this error: error C2228: left of '.loadSAG' must have class/struct/union ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is Agent theAgent(void); the function declaration?

Comment: That's what the compiler thinks, but that's not what's intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Agent theAgent(void);
```

This is a function declaration, just change it to:

```
Agent theAgent;
```

Comment: Also, you don't need to write `void` in functions that take no parameters

Comment: I actually never used void like this before, but I used VC++ generator for the class and I thought what the hell, let's stick with this. so.. solved :)

Answer (score 4):

Compiler thinks

```
Agent theAgent(void);
```

This to be a function declaration.

```
Agent theAgent;
```

Comment: Be warned with the second option however, you will be calling an assignment operator.

Comment: Actually copy constructor. But I removed it anyways, as I do not like this style.

Comment: Actually neither of them (to my surprise). I posted this question, copy constructor is optimized away by NRVO

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
Agent theAgent(void);
```

Is actually viewed by the compiler as declaring the function `theAgent` that takes no arguments and returns an Agent.

This is explained the the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.19).

To call the default constructor and set up an object of type `Agent` (as opposed to the statement above that's interpreted as a function declaration,) you can just declare `theAgent` without using parentheses at all, as in:

```
Agent theAgent;
```

All normal member calls, such as `loadSAG` will work as expected after this point.

As an alternative, if you must have the object on the heap, use this instead:

```
Agent* theAgent = new Agent();  // Notice the *
theAgent->loadSAG();            // Use -> instead of .

// The code where theAgent is used

delete theAgent;  // This frees the memory allocated by new
```

Answer (score 1):

If by
`Agent theAgent(void);`
you meant function declaration then you probably forgot to add `()` to the function call

`int m = theAgent().loadSAG();`

If you wanted to define a variable with the name `theAgent` then you have added extra `(void)`.
and instead you should wrote

`Agent theAgent;`

Comment: Isn't that just going to try and call an operator() on the 'theAgent' object, for which there is not one defined, but if there were it would then attempt to use .loadSAG(); on the return value of the () operator...

Comment: That's not helpful to a beginner. If you are going to cheat like that at least explain the mad mumbo jumbo you are doing.

Comment: Answering the question I thought that in the question it is a function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

When calling a default (parameterless) constructor you do so without the '()'. Ie. Try constructing your agent object:

```
Agent theAgent;
```

Answer (score -3):

try

```
Agent theAgent = new Agent();
theAgent.loadSAG();
```

The error message looks like you never instantiated an Agent object before you tried to use it.

Comment: This might work (and indeed will, since you're using the default copy constructor,) but *it will leak memory.* This is because you are assigning the contents of the `new Agent` (allocated on the heap) to `theAgent`. Since C++ isn't garbage collected and you aren't keeping a reference to the allocated memory to delete, this memory will not be reclaimed until the program terminates. Don't do it this way.

Comment: @Cristian. You are correct but that goes beyond the question he asked.
@those who think that there is no new operator in C++ and decided to down vote an answer that was accepted by the person who asked the question. You're wrong.

Comment: @ChadNC: I didn't down vote because "I don't think there is a new operator in C++," I down voted because it's being used inappropriately. To get use the `new` operator without leaking memory, you need `theAgent` to be an `Agent*`, and all members would be accessed with the pointer to member operator `->`. This leaves the pointer accessible so that the memory can be `delete`d later.

Comment: @ChadNC: Never mind memory leaks, `theAgent` needs to be an `Agent*` just to get it to compile in C++.

Comment: @Troubadour: Hey, I missed that one. Good catch.

Comment: you know even if my question seemed like a beginner's one I can handle dynamic allocation.. it's just I haven't used c++ for a long long time and was quite comfortable with the leisure of javascript.

Comment: I'm even more surprised then that you accepted an uncompilable and memory leaking answer when there are correct ones.